# Unable to run hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am new to hadoop and ubuntu. I just wanted to start hadoop and I am trying this command

```
bin/start-dfs.sh
```

but this gives following messages

> bin/dfs.sh permission denied

I also try these commands but unable to start hadoop.

```
sudo chmod -R og+rx /media/Entertainment/hadoop/bin/

sudo chown -R hadoop /media/Entertainment/hadoop/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the `.sh` executable.

For example like this for all executable files in Hadoop's binary directory:

```
sudo chmod +x bin/*.sh
sudo chmod +x bin/hadoop
```

Comment: hello Thomams Thanks for your time.I try these commands but I am unable to change its permission.it is stil like -rw------- 1 sunil sunil  1066 2012-03-21 01:57 start-all.sh

Comment: Then you should put your question to http://superuser.com/ and ask why you can't change permissions.